# Posible bug filtering many to many self-referencing relationship in Doctrine 2.5?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I'm developing a social network in which users can follow and have followers. Followers and users being followed are implemented as collections using doctrine. I want to be able to filter this collections without loading the whole collection, since doctrine 2.5 this should be posible using criteria and matching, the filtering i want to do should be prety simple i want to hide blocked users. So lets say user A blocks user B, and user B is in the follower list of user C then user B should be hidded so user A can't see it in the follower list of user C.

This was my first approach using criteria:

```
    public function getFollowerUsers(User $user, $page){
    $filter_ids = array_merge((array)$user->getBlockedUserIds(), (array)$user->getBlockingUserIds());
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->where(Criteria::expr()->notIn('id', $filter_ids))
            ->setFirstResult($page * User::USERS_PER_PAGE)
            ->setMaxResults(User::USERS_PER_PAGE);
    return $this->followers->matching($criteria);
}
```

This should work, but the SQL being executed is the following:

```
SELECT te.id AS id, te.user_login AS user_login, te.user_pass AS user_pass, te.user_nicename AS user_nicename, te.user_email AS user_email, te.user_url AS user_url, te.user_registered AS user_registered, te.user_activation_key AS user_activation_key, te.user_status AS user_status, te.display_name AS display_name FROM users te JOIN followers t ON t.following_user_id = te.id WHERE t.user_id = ? AND te.ids = ?' with params ["1", ["7","37"]]
```

Note that i changed `Criteria::expr()->notIn('id', $filter_ids)` for `Criteria::expr()->notIn('ids', $filter_ids)` so I could see the SQL being executed, the important thing here is that doctrine is using te.ids = when it should use te.ids NOT LIKE, it doesn't matter which operator i use doctrine always change it to =, so it seems like it only works with `Criteria::expr()->eq('id', 1)`, am I doing anything wrong or this is a bug?. If i change the sql generated by doctrine for not in it works as I expect to work!

My current solution was creating a service so the entity doesn't know anything about the EntityManager:

```
class UserService {

/* $em EntityManager */
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function getFollowingUsers(\models\Users $user, \models\Users $user_querying, $page, $users_per_page){
    $filter_ids = implode(",", array_merge((array)$user_querying->getBlockedUserIds(), (array)$user_querying->getBlockingUserIds()));
    //var_dump($filter_ids);
    $user_following = $this->em->createQuery("SELECT u,f FROM \models\WpUsers u JOIN u.following f WHERE u.id = :user_id AND f.id NOT IN($filter_ids)")
            ->setParameter('user_id', $user->getId())
            ->setFirstResult($page * $users_per_page)
            ->setMaxResults($users_per_page)
            ->getResult();
    return $user_following[0]->getFollowingUsers();
}
```

}

And the call it this way:

```
$service = new \services\UserService($this->em);
$following_users = $service->getFollowingUsers($user_list, $user);
```

This works properly and it seems like I'm not loading the whole collection to filter, but i would like to be able to do it the other way since it is much clear and more elegant

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to be a problem as well. Any comparison ("neq", "lt", etc.) turns out to be "=" in the SQL call. I'm using Doctrine v2.5.2.

Searching many-to-many relationships with Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria was unsupported in versions <2.5, so the new functionality must still be in development.